# Why doesn't mov set the zero flag?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, eflags

What is the reason why adding a value into a register doesn't alter the zero flag? For example, let's say I have:

```
mov array(,%rdi,8), %eax
```

I would need to also do a second operation to check to see if the value moved was zero, something like:

```
cmp $0, %eax
```

But what's the rationale behind doing this? Is the circuit much simpler / instruction much faster on just a straight move operation without altering the flags (it wouldn't need to hit the ALU?) or why aren't the flags set?

Comment: Some other ISAs, for example ARM, allow optional flag setting on a per-instruction basis, including for `mov` between registers (but still not load/store, which use a different mnemonic / opcode, unlike in x86).  So on ARM you can `movs r1, r0` to copy-and-test.  But yes historically, "the ALU" handled flags and MOV doesn't need the ALU; it would have made old micro-coded CPUs slower.  Modern x86-64 designs could probably build a `test reg,reg` into the load units without a problem.  (But not store, stores don't produce an integer result so it would hurt efficiency.)

Comment: Also, it lets you keep a flag result around for a bit while loading or storing something; useful with a very limited number of integer regs before x86-64, and especially even older 8-bit micros.

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the performance of `mov mem, %eax ; test %eax, %eax` (which should be better than `cmp`), versus `xor %eax, %eax; or mem, %eax` (alternatively replace `or` by `add`, `xor`, etc), since zeroing a register is supposed to be nearly free.

Comment: I assume the inventors of the instruction set are not around to answer this question.  So you just have to accept the instruction set as defined.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Interestingly, AArch64 doesn't include a mnemonic for `movs x1, x0`, even though it seems like there would be several ways to reproduce it as an alias: `ands x1, x0, x0`,  `adds x1, xzr, x0`, et cetera.  Kind of surprising given their liberal use of aliases for just about everything else.  Looks like they did include one in SVE, however.